# Decrypting an Affine Cipher with Modulus

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to decrypt the ciphertext vczkh which I know was encoded using an affine cipher with the equation 7x + 8(mod 26). This makes my decryption function p = (c – b) * a^-1 (mod 26) where b = 8, a = 7, c = number corresponding with cipher character starting from 0, and p is the same for plaintext. Since I can't have a fraction I calculated that 11 is congruent to 7 making my function p = (c - 8) * 11. Running this for all five letters gives me NMFWP but I know the answer is supposed to be NOVEL. I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. If the modulus is 26 the alphabet should include only 26 characters, yet your problem statement suggests it includes upper and lower case and digits, which would be 62 characters at  minimum.

Comment: Ok, your problem statement is *very* sloppy. The ciphertext is 'VCZKH' and the encoding is 'A' -> 0, 'B' -> 1, ..., 'Z' -> 25. You have simply computed 7^(-1) mod 26 incorrectly. 7^(-1) mod 26 is simply the value t such that 7*t = 1 mod 26. You can easily try all 26 possible values of t to find the one that works.

Answer (score 0):

In order to decrypt and affine cipher given `a` and `b` you need to use **Dk = a^-1(y-b) mod m** where `m` depends in the cardinality of the alphabet you are currently using (English 26, Italian 21, ...), `a^-1 = m-a` and `k = (a, b)`.

For instance, *vczkh* with `a=7` and `b=8` gets decrypted into *nqlmh* given `a^-1 = m - a = 26 - 7 = 19`

So for `v`, since `v` is at position `21` in the english alphabet:

`v` -> `19(21-8) mod 26` -> `247 mod 26` -> `13` that corresponds to `n`

[Here's](https://github.com/AndreaM16/Affine-Cipher-Simulator) a **Javascript** script I wrote

```
//Getting Args from console
var args = {
    "operation" : process.argv[2],
    "a"         : parseInt(process.argv[3]),
    "b"         : parseInt(process.argv[4]),
    "word"      : process.argv[5]             
};

var encryptedWord = [];
var decryptedWord = [];

if(!args.operation || !args.a || !args.b || !args.word){
    console.log("Arguments are missing, please, use: node  \"encrypt/decrypt\" a b word");
    return;
} else {
    if(typeof args.a === 'number' || typeof args.b === 'number'){
        if(typeof args.word !== 'string'){
            console.log("Word must be a string");
            return;
        } else {
            // If a and m are coprimes
            if(gcdCalc(args.a, 26) === 1){
                if(args.operation === "encrypt"){
                    encryptWord().then(function(encrWord){
                        console.log("Word "+args.word+" got encrypted into "+encrWord);
                    });
                } else if(args.operation === "decrypt"){
                    decryptWord().then(function(decrWord){
                        console.log("Ciphetext "+args.word+" got decrypted into "+decrWord);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("Invalid operation specified. Use encrypt or decrypt.");
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                console.log("a "+args.a+ " and m 26 are not coprimes");
                return;
            }
        }   
    } else {
        console.log("You must assign an Integer number to a and b. Remember that a must be coprime with m (26)");
        return;
    }
}

function gcdCalc(a, b) {
    if (b) {
        return gcdCalc(b, a % b);
    } else {
        return Math.abs(a);
    }
};

function encryptWord(){
   return new Promise( function(resolve){
      var chars = args.word.split("");
      var currInt = 0;
      var currEnc = "";
      chars.forEach( function( currChar){
        currInt = parseInt(currChar, 36) - 10;
        // E(a,b)(n) = an + b mod 26
        currEnc = mod((args.a * currInt + args.b), 26);
        encryptedWord.push(String.fromCharCode(97 + currEnc));
      });
      return resolve(encryptedWord.join(""));   
    });
}

function decryptWord(){
    return new Promise( function(resolve){
      var chars = args.word.split("");
      var currInt = 0;
      var currEnc = "";
      //a^-1 = m - a
      var a_1 = 26 - args.a;
      chars.forEach( function( currChar){
        currInt = parseInt(currChar, 36) - 10;
        // D(y) = a^-1 * (y - b) mod 26
        currEnc = mod((a_1 * (currInt - args.b)), 26);
        decryptedWord.push(String.fromCharCode(97 + currEnc));
      });
      return resolve(decryptedWord.join(""));   
    });
}

function mod(n, m) {
    var remain = n % m;
    return Math.floor(remain >= 0 ? remain : remain + m);
};
```

To run it you need `node`, then, you can use it:

- Encrypt : `node affine-cipher.js encrypt 5 8 affine` that becomes `ihhwvc`
- Decrypt : `node affine-cipher.js decrypt 5 8 ihhwvc` that becomes `affine`

Notice that `a` and `m` MUST be coprime. For instance `gcd(a, m)` MUST be 1.

The total number of possible keys is `312` since `a` may vary in `12` different numbers which are coprime with `26` and `b` may vary in all `26` different number, so `12*26=312`.

Hope I've been helpful.